# Externalizable array in Java

Tags: java, serialization, serializable, externalizable

I need to send over the network an array of [`Externalizable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) objects for maintainability and performance reasons ([`Serializable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is not enough).

The documentation says that all arrays in Java are [`Serializable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Is it possible to have an array that is also [`Externalizable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html)? If not, what are the workarounds to still have benefits of [`Externalizable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) and send a bunch of these objects over the network?

Comment: Stringify to JSON like half of the world do? Serialize to byte array and send over?

Comment: @Antoniossss this would be true for a new solution, but I just need to extend current one which uses serialization

Comment: @Antoniossss he said "for performance reasons", so that would rule out using JSON to send an array. It would probably be worse than serializing it.

Comment: It's an array of what, by-the-way?

Comment: The funny thig is tha externalizable is serializable - how does that make you gain performance ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily make arrays externalizable (I am guessing it might be possible with byte-code manipulation or something).

However, what you probably are doing is not sending the raw array, but sending some other class that includes the raw array. So you can implement Externalizable in that class such that it can send and receive all its contents in the format you desire.

In the case that the array is really the only thing you want to send, this other class could be a simple wrapper.

Comment: I'm sending a raw array, that's my interface that I must conform to

Comment: So your interface is send(Externalizable e) or something like that? Maybe give an example.